# Unable to install Firebase commandline tools in Ubuntu using npm

Tags: node.js, firebase, ubuntu, npm, firebase-cli

When I tried to install Firebase command line tools in my Ubuntu machine, I am getting the following error:

> `rollbackFailedOptional : verb npm-session xxxxx`
>   node version installed is `8.9.4` and npm version is `5.6.0`.

How can I solve this?

### Update

I upgraded nodejs version to `9.5.0` and now I get a different error:

> `fetchMetadata : sill resolveWithNewModule firebase-tools@3.17.4 checking installable status`

These are the commands I run to set up Nodejs and Firebase tools

First I run this command

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash`

and then

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

and at last to install Firebase tools:

`sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`

### Update 2

Installed nvm and reinstalled nodejs using `nvm install node` (when I tried `sudo install node` is gives error, `sudo: nvm: command not found`)
and then ran the command ,`sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` it made some checks and fell into some sort of infinite loop, (I think so, because it is printing the same 3 lines again and again), it is printing

```
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp/9.5.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
```

and I have press `ctrl+c` to stop that after 3-4 minutes.

Here is the screenshot of terminal:

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the entire output of the command you ran?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited my question and added the commands. The nodejs installation part was successful and completed without any error/warning. This is the only line printed in the terminal when i ran the command to install firebase tools, `fetchMetadata : sill resolveWithNewModule firebase-tools@3.17.4 checking installable status`

Comment: Consider using nvm to install node in your home directory and put it in your PATH first.  That might prevent any sort of permission problems.

Comment: let me try, i will update you soon

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited and added an update

Comment: Install nvm in your home directory, not using any package managers, not using sudo.  The idea is to stop trying to write files under /usr/lib or other places that require root.

Comment: when i re-run the command it is showing this 

`sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/usr/bin/firebase -> /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase
+ firebase-tools@3.17.4
updated 1 package in 67.425s
` is it a successful install?

Comment: Looks like it.  Can you run `firebase`?

Comment: Yes!!! when i ran just firebase, it is showing help !!!!!